# Não mostrar produto inativo na busca de produtos

Tags: mysql

Possuo um trecho de código que faz uma busca ao meu BD pelo termo, até tudo correto, mas tenho produtos que estão inativos e não deveriam ser pegos e estão aparecendo, o código está assim, devo estar errando na query.

```
    $query_rsBuscaFiltro = "SELECT marca.descricao AS marca, 
                         produtos.id_produto, 
                         produtos.id_departamento,
                         produtos.id_subdepartamento,
                         produtos.id_marca, 
                         produtos.descricao AS prodDesc, 
                         produtos.lancamento,
                         produtos.codigo_msb,
                         produtos.status
                    FROM produtos INNER JOIN marca ON (produtos.id_marca = marca.id_marca) 
                   WHERE (produtos.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')  OR 
                         (produtos.resumo LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')     OR 
                         (produtos.codigo_msb LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%') OR 
                         (produtos.detalhes LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')   OR 
                         (marca.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%') AND
                         produtos.status = 1 "; 
                         echo $query_rsBusca;
$rsBuscaFiltro = mysql_query($query_rsBuscaFiltro, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsBuscaFiltro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsBuscaFiltro);
$totalRows_rsBuscaFiltro = mysql_num_rows($rsBuscaFiltro);
```

Comment: O que diz que (não) está inativo? O `status` ser `1`?

Comment: Poderia tentar algo como? `WHERE (produtos.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%'  OR produtos.resumo LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%' OR produtos.codigo_msb LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%' OR 
produtos.detalhes LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%'   OR marca.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%') AND produtos.status = 1 "; `

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Também acho que o problema é de precedência.

Comment: @bfavaretto Acredito ser isso... só esperando ele testar agora :)

Comment: Olá @RafaelWithoeft e bfavaretto estou testando, obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Olá @bfavaretto, isso mesmo se o produto está como 1 está ativo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que você controla os produtos inativos pelo produtos.status. Na sua query ele só se refere ao último OR. Então se um dos OR anteriores derem positivo ele retorna o produto. Você tem que reescrever assim:

```
$query_rsBuscaFiltro = "SELECT marca.descricao AS marca, 
                         produtos.id_produto, 
                         produtos.id_departamento,
                         produtos.id_subdepartamento,
                         produtos.id_marca, 
                         produtos.descricao AS prodDesc, 
                         produtos.lancamento,
                         produtos.codigo_msb,
                         produtos.status
                    FROM produtos INNER JOIN marca ON (produtos.id_marca = marca.id_marca) 
                   WHERE ((produtos.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')  OR 
                         (produtos.resumo LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')     OR 
                         (produtos.codigo_msb LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%') OR 
                         (produtos.detalhes LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')   OR 
                         (marca.descricao LIKE '%".$pesquisa."%')) AND
                         produtos.status = 1 "; 
                         echo $query_rsBusca;
$rsBuscaFiltro = mysql_query($query_rsBuscaFiltro, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsBuscaFiltro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsBuscaFiltro);
$totalRows_rsBuscaFiltro = mysql_num_rows($rsBuscaFiltro);
```

Acrescentando os () no WHERE antes do AND, ele vai testar se algum LIKE combina e se der positivo ele vai testar se o status é = 1.

Comment: Olá @Ricardo BRGWeb, muito obrigado pela excelente dica, estou testando.

Comment: Eu errava isso o tempo todo...rs. Bom que ajudou!

Comment: Olá @Ricardo BRGWeb, me ajudou muito essa sua dica, agradeço.

Answer (score -2):

Altere a ultima linha da query para: `produtos.status = 0 ";`

Comment: Como você sabe o que significam os status do banco de dados dele?